# Use private copy of global variable with OpenMP in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, global-variables, openmp

I want to do something along the lines of

```
int getal = 0;


void incrementAndPrint() {
  getal = getal + 1;
  printf("%d\n", getal);
}


void main() {
  int times = 100;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int n = 0; n < times; n++) {
    incrementAndPrint(n);
  }
}


/*
Desired output:
1
1
1
1
...
*/
```

What happens right now, of course is that I get the numbers 0 to 99 in unpredictable order.

Is there a way to make private copies of global variables in every thread without having to alter a lot of existing code?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `threadprivate` directive.  Why your question has been closed for being a duplicate of one asking about the use of pthreads escapes me.

Comment: My entire code is parallelisable, so I ended up just writing a ruby script to start processes on all cores with `taskset`.

Comment: Well that was a cop out.